# Подскажите как оптимальнее всего сравнить две даты в одном формате

Tags: php, дата

Через GET приходит `date` в формате `"Y.m.d"`, на диске лежат файлы...
Надо привести `filemtime` файла и строкового `date` к общему типу без времени(только даты), и сравнить.

Как это сделать в минимум строк?

Comment: https://php.ru/manual/datetime.diff.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `filemtime()`:
>    Возвращает время последнего изменения указанного файла, или `FALSE` в случае возникновения ошибки. **Время возвращается в формате временной метки Unix, который подходит для передачи в качестве аргумента функции `date()`.**

```
$ftime = date("Y.m.d", filemtime($path));
// $_GET['date']  == $ftime
```

Comment: Да это понятно... Но `date` вернёт строку в заданном формате, а мне надо сравнить 2 даты - одна приходит в Get, в виде строки, вторая из файла в виде timestamp. При использовании на строке `DateTime::createFromFormat` получается объект... А мне бы в идеале привести дату в get к таймштампу с указанной датой и нулевым временем, а у таймштама файла обнулить часы/минуты/секунды, оставив только дату... и сравнить 2 штампа дат... Вот это как сделать без лишних преобразований?

Comment: @Iceman вы написали, что входящая строка в формате `y.m.d`,  вот и сравните две строки, зачем их к датам-то приводить?

Comment: Да, точно... Со строками тоже сработает. Принимаю ответ, НО... Сравнение числовых данных работает быстрее, если нужно пройтись по массиву файлов, которых много, вот такая конструкция отрабатывает почему-то быстрее `$day=intval(DateTime::createFromFormat($format,$date)->getTimestamp()/86400)*86400;
for($i = 0; $i < $fcount; ++$i)
 if($day!==intval(filemtime($DirPath.$files[$i])/86400)*86400)
  unset($files[$i]);`

Answer (score 0):

Я бы не стал ничего сравнивать с тем, что придет в GET без обработки -

```
if(strtotime(date("Y.m.d", filemtime($path))) == strtotime($_GET['date'])) {
    // .....
}
```